# python histogram how to find the midpoint of bin with the maximum frequency

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, frequency, bins

I want to find the midpoint of the bin with the maximum frequency. How I can get the value?

Using matplotlib I draw histogram with code:

```
num_bins = 25
weights = (1 / data['day'].shape[0]) * np.ones_like(data['day'])
n, bin_cuts, patches = plt.hist(data['day'], num_bins, weights=weights)
```

and get this histogram of 25 bins.
I use .max() but it gives the only max point of the whole data.

Comment: Use `numpy.argmax` to get the index of the maximum.

Answer (score 1):

Try using -

```
0.5 * ( edges[1:] + edges[:-1] )
```